# What is the problem of my dialogflow request in the code (it works with postman)?

Tags: javascript, json, dialogflow-es, chatbot, api-ai

I have a problem with my chatbot Application. I just don't find the mistake why I can't call the dialogflow api with my request from code tough it works with the exact same request from postman. Even the dialogflow support says that the request is correct.

Can it be blocked somehow from dialogflow? Or does it not automatically change the javascript code into a json object?

Below I send you the code of my application (code snippet 1), the actual result from the code request (code snippet 2), the wanted result as it comes back when I use postman (code snippet 3), and the screenshot of the intent in dialogflow (screenshot 1).

**code snippet 1: code of my application**

```
const fetchAnswerFromDialogflow = async (userInput, currentChatbotInEdit) => {

const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + clientToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      },
    };

const request = {
      queryParams: {
        contexts: [
          {
            name:
              `projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/sessions/myteachingbot-session${state.sessionId}/contexts/Chatbotcontext726`,
            lifespanCount: 1,
          },
          {
            name:
              `projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/sessions/myteachingbot-session${state.sessionId}/contexts/Chatbotcontext7262`
              inputContext1,
            lifespanCount: 1,
          },
        ],
        resetContexts: true,
      },
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: userInput,
          languageCode: "en-US",
        },
      },
    };
try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/sessions/myteachingbot-session${state.sessionId}:detectIntent`,
        request,
        config
      );
      console.log(res);

}
```

**code snippet 2: the actual result from the code request**

```
{
  "responseId": "8a9ead3d-f3ea-4a75-b110-257454069382-425db6e2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "start",
    "parameters": {},
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

**code snippet 3: the wanted result that I get returned from postman:**

```
{
  "responseId": "f8ea7646-576a-4789-a88f-d0f80416de84-425db6e2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "start",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Frage 1",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Frage 1"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/70aa4273-5368-4a40-acc3-484c8ad415df",
      "displayName": "Frage7261"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot of the intent in dialogflow console]

Comment: Really. Asking the exact same question over and over doesn't help us help you. If you have additional information, updating your original question is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the Intent you've provided is the Intent you expect to be triggered - it won't be triggered by any of the Training Phrases since an Event is set for it.

Dialogflow will only trigger an Intent that contains an Event if that Event is sent as part of the Detect Intent request.